# iTunes on iPhone not working properly

Tags: iphone, itunes, bluetooth, playlist

iTunes on my iPhone used to start playlist via bluetooth where it left off. Now it always starts at the beginning of the playlist when it reconnects. How to I get iTunes to work properly again?

Comment: It does the same on my CarPlay, wired, since iOS 12.